# Datagrid only works when AutoGenerateColumns = true

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

I have a datagrid with an itemssource

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SelectedCollection, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

when I set AutogenerateColums = true, everything works.
But when I set it to alse add the following line to show just 1 column:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Width="2*" Binding="{Binding Path=Domain}" Header="Domein"/>
```

Exception:

> Add value to collection of type
>   'System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection' threw an exception Operation
>   is not valid while ItemsSource is in use. Access and modify elements
>   with ItemsControl.ItemsSource instead.

I'm not trying to add anything to the collection anywhere.

On the same page I have another datagrid with a different collection that just works the way I described here above without any problems. The only differences I can think of is that the second collection is made up of object in another namespace but it should just exist in the same datacontext.

Anyone any ideas?

EDIT: In design time I get the following message:
Cannot resolve property Domain in Data Context of type ....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should **add custom column inside Columns tag**. I suspect you are adding directly under DataGrid tag. It should be:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SelectedCollection, Mode=TwoWay}">
  <DataGrid.Columns>
     <DataGridTextColumn/>
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: THANK YOU - I just looked over it ! I'll accept your answer in 8 minutes.

Comment: +1 and pls remove the TwoWay Mode - it makes no sense or does your datagrid ever set the itemssource?